# Take in Strings with spaces

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to get into Java and I decided to jump straight into user input. Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class HelloWorld{

 public static void main(String []args){
    System.out.println("Enter a phrase to mutate: \n"); 

    Scanner userinput = new Scanner(System.in);
    String phrase = userinput.next();
    System.out.println(phrase);

    String phrasemutation1 = phrase.toUpperCase();
    System.out.println(phrasemutation1);

    String phrasemutation2 = phrasemutation1.replace('I','X');
    System.out.println(phrasemutation2);

    //String phrasemutation3 = phrasemutation2.substring(17, 23);
    //System.out.println(phrasemutation3);
 }
}
```

However, when entering in anything with a space, only the first word is taken in. Searching the site just gives me results on how to remove them, but I'd like to keep the spaces intact. Is there a way to do this, or at the very least replace them with underscores?

Also, if there's some beginner formatting errors I'm making I'd love to hear them.

Comment: Depending on the platform you're running on (Windows, Linux, ...) you might have to wrap the phrase in double quotes or something else (probably single quotes).

Comment: Use `nextLine` to read a whole line instead of `next` which only reads one word. You can find more information in the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html).

Answer (score 3):

```
String phrase = userinput.next();
```

> Finds and returns the next complete token from this scanner. A complete token is preceded and followed by input that matches the delimiter pattern. This method may block while waiting for input to scan, even if a previous invocation of hasNext() returned true.
>   Change to:

```
  String phrase = userinput.nextLine();
```

> Advances this scanner past the current line and returns the input that was skipped. This method returns the rest of the current line, excluding any line separator at the end. The position is set to the beginning of the next line.
>   Since this method continues to search through the input looking for a line separator, it may buffer all of the input searching for the line to skip if no line separators are present.

Answer (score 2):

You would want to familiarize yourself with the Javadoc. [Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)'s explicitly states:

> A Scanner breaks its input into tokens using a delimiter pattern, which by default matches whitespace.

So each `next` gives you a word which is separated by whitespaces:

> The `next()` and `hasNext()` methods and their primitive-type companion methods (such as `nextInt()` and `hasNextInt()`) first skip any input that matches the delimiter pattern, and then attempt to return the next token.

You can change the delimiter with `useDelimiter` or in the constructor to match new lines.

As suggested by everyone else here, you can just use `nextLine` instead.

---

As for other improvements of your code, I would acquaint myself with `System.lineSeparator()` instead of all sorts of `\n`s and `\r`s.

Answer (score 1):

Use `userinput.nextLine()` to get the whole like of text rather than individual strings.

`userinput.next()` will only get the next string (string delimited by a space).

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried

```
String phrase = userinput.nextLine();
```

The [nextLine()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine--) method reads everything, including spaces until it encounters a newline.